# Inconsistent tags ns2 and ns-3

Tags: discussion, tags

There are tags [ns2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ns2) and [ns-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ns-3) which refer to Network Simulator, just different versions. Even the explanation text in ns2 talks about ns-2. Probably the tag should be renamed to ns-2 and maybe add synonyms without dash, though I assume people would find it without also.

Comment: can we rename those to network-simulator? `ns` is a bit unclear what it is.

Comment: @DanielA.White That might be the best case, while having ns-2 and ns-3 as synonyms

Comment: Err. no, that will defeat the whole point of having network-simulator (the complete name) tag.